Deploying Gatsby React app to github pages
I followed the instrution in gatsby document(gatsby). I keep geting this error. When I run npm run deploy
Error: Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/StudHamza/hamza.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/StudHamza/hamza.git (push)

  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public",
}

Gatsby-config.js:
  flags: {
    DEV_SSR: true
  },
  pathPrefix: "/hamza",
  plugins: [],

}

Trying to deploy gatsby app on github page.
